# Comparing real and simulated data

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have built a simulator of a real system and obtained some simulated data, and I would like to know to what extent the simulated data approximates the real data. Do you have any suggestions on how to compare the real versus the simulated data?

(Statistics is not my strong suit, so I have googled and tried to find an appropriate method. Then I found myself drowning in the ocean of statistic terms... I would really appreciate any helps from you!)

Edit: My simulator simulates a pumping station, and the data that I want to compare are for example the simulated water level and real measurements of the water level of a station. My goal is to obtain an quantitative measurement on how much the simulated water level deviate from the real data.

Comment: Do you have a theoretical distribution of your real data? Or actual data? How much? Is your goal to compare these two distributions, to check if they are distributed similarly?

Comment: What has been used (in Approximate Bayesian Computation), is to calculate summary statistics under the real and simulated data and calculate their distance. For example, a summary statistics could be the mean, the variance etc.

Comment: Might check out Benford's Law.

Answer (score 2):

No model would ever be perfect, so it is rather pointless to expect that the simulated data would perfectly match the real data. Moreover, when you build a model then you focus on modeling some particular properties of the system. For example, if you simulated car traffic in Berlin, you probably would not care about things as the brands or colors of the cars. So start with asking yourself what are the properties of the system you care about.

When you know that, look at the relevant data and compare it visually ([histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), [density plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), [scatter plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot), [ECDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)s, etc), compare the summary statistics ([mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean), [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median), [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)), [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), [quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile), etc), check if multivariate relationships between variables hold (e.g. [correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation) between variables), you can also use hypothesis tests to compare the distributions (e.g. [Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)). But again, you need to ask yourself what of those are relevant to your problem.

If you say that statistics is not your strength, this may be hard. You should probably review some materials on exploratory data analysis, statistics basics (to understand the summary statistics better), and hypothesis testing. This is a statistics problem, so you'll need statistics knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My simulator simulates a pumping station, and the data that I want to compare are for example the simulated water level and real measurements of the water level of a station. My goal is to obtain an quantitative measurement on how much the simulated water level deviate from the real data. I suspect that summary statistics may be sufficient, like the mean difference between each data points in the simulated and real data sets? And maybe distributions are not that relevant to my problem?

Comment: @IsTuseday this is a question you need to ask yourself, based on your domain knowledge.